# Read characters from a file and store them in a variable in C

Tags: c

I am trying to read character by character from a file and store the characters in a variable.

Only the content from the first line of the file is required so I am using `\n` or `EOF` to stop reading. It is required to store `SPACE` also.

Here is my program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  char ch;
  char txt[30];
  int len;
  fp=fopen("~/hello.txt","r");
  ch=fgetc(fp);
  while(ch != EOF || ch!="\n")
  {
    txt[len]=ch;
    len++;
    ch=fgetc(fp);
  }
   puts(txt);
}
```

But I am getting a warning while compiling like comparison between pointer and integer. And when I run it I am getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: Are you sure that your first line contains less than 30 character?! Otherwise, you will overwrite your buffer `txt` ...

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing to the wrong thing. Try:

```
ch != '\n'
      ^  ^
```

Also, as spotted in other answers, you're using `len` without initializing it.

Finally, you do realize `fgets` can do that as well. You could rewrite the thing to:

```
if (fgets(txt, sizeof txt, fp))
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

1) `len` is not initiated

```
int len=0;
```

2) From [fgetc()](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/) page:

```
int fgetc ( FILE * stream );
```

so  the `fgetc()` return `int` and not `char` so you have to define `ch` as `int`

```
int ch;
```

3) In addition of the ***cnicutar*** remark, the `while` condition should be checked with the `&&` and not with `||`:

```
while(ch != EOF && ch!='\n')
```

4) You have to add null terminator charachter at the end of your `txt` buffer after finishing reading from file.

Add this line after the `while` loop

```
txt[len]='\0';
```

---

**BTW** you can read the first line with `fscanf()` it's more easier. Just use the following code

```
fscanf(fp, "%29[^\n]", txt);
```

The `"%[^\n]"` means that `fscanf` will read all characters from `fp` except the `'\n'` charachter and it will stop reading if it gets this charachter. So the  `fscanf` will read all characters from `fp` till it find `'\n'` character and save them into the buffer `txt` with null terminator charchter at the end.

The `"%29[^\n]"` means that `fscanf` will read all characters from `fp` till it find `'\n'` character or till it reach 29 readed charchters and save them into the buffer `txt` with null terminator charchter at the end.

Comment: i have changed int len=0 and doing closing file but still i get some junk values printed. @mohamed this works fine for me fscanf(fp,"%29"[^\n]",txt)  but i am not understanding it. what exactly happens in that line

Comment: @NaggappanRM answer updated concerning the explanation of fscanf(fp,"%29"[^\n]",txt)

Comment: @NaggappanRM your code display junk values because it contains other bug. answer updated with fixed bugs

Comment: using this only first line i am able to scan incase if i need to scan 2nd line also what will happen, because i am getting junk character when i scan 2nd line. Where the file pointer will stand after performing this this one?

Comment: @NaggappanRM what are you talking about? solution with fscan or solution without fscanf. Any way I suggest to you to open another question for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`len` is not initialised so you're probably attempting to write way beyond the end of `txt`.  The fix is simple - initialise it to `0` on declaration

```
int len = 0;
```

In addition to the error pointed out by cnicutar, you should also check the return value from `fopen` before using `fp`.

Comment: Why call `fclose` before the end of the program ?

Comment: I agree its not absolutely necessary on the platforms the poster is likely running on but freeing resources you've allocated seems like a good habit to get into.

Comment: I'm not sure it's platform dependent. Doesn't the standard guarantee that at exit `stdio` streams are closed ?

Comment: I didn't know that.  I suspect that wasn't the reason why the poster omitted cleanup :).  Regardless, that part of my answer obviously isn't very helpful - I'll remove it.

Comment: No, wait. I'm not sure the standar guarantees it, I was asking you :-))

Comment: Found it. *If the main function returns to its original caller, or if the exit function is called, all open files are closed (hence all output streams are flushed) before program termination.*

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  char ch;
  char txt[30];
  int len = 0;
  fp=fopen("~/hello.txt","r");
  if(!fp) {
    printf("Cannot open file!\n");
    return;
  }
  ch=fgetc(fp);
  while(ch != EOF && ch!= '\n' && len < 30)
  {
    txt[len] = ch;
    len++;
    ch=fgetc(fp);
  }
  txt[len] = 0;
  puts(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This program may help you to solve your problem.

```
     #include<stdio.h>

     int main()
     {
       FILE *fp;
       int ch;
       char txt[300];
       int len=0;
       fp=fopen("tenlines.txt","r");

       do{
           ch=fgetc(fp);
           txt[len]=ch;
           len++;
         } while(ch!=EOF && ch!='\n');
     fclose(fp);
     puts(txt);

     return 0;
    }
```